# Photoshop make texture fit shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to fit a texture inside this shape but the main thing is that I want it to continue on both sides of A and B from the bottom center, I dont want the texture to continue under the black parts of A and B then continue on the other side. In other words I want the texture to automatically fit the shape in a continous way. Is there any way to do this?

I've tryed to find a way to do it and searched google but I couldnt find anything. Hope someone can help

[image]

Many Thanks!!

Comment: Are 3D Studio and similars an options? Illustrator? or are we limited to photoshop ?

Comment: maybe "puppet warp"? Cs5 or newer I think.

Comment: with puppet the problem is that he still wouldn't be able to "split" the image through those cuts (a and b), I think he would have to split the image into 3 layers first, warp them individually and then merge them down

Comment: Show us the texture as well :)

Answer (score 1):

> continue on both sides of A and B from the bottom center, I dont want the texture to continue under the black parts of A and B then continue on the other side

I'm not quite sure what you mean by this, but have you tried placing the texture on a layer above the shape, right clicking the texture layer, and clicking create layer mask? After that, you could erase, or cut out the areas you don't want the texture showing.

If you're saying you want the texture inside the shape you've shown us a screen shot of, but not covering the black portions, simple select the shape layer, use your magic wand tool at 0 tolerance and select the middle portion, then go to your texture layer, invert the selection and cut.

Comment: Well then OP might as well place the texture layer underneath and avoid all cutting/erasing work. I don't believe that's what OP meant. Then again I'm not 100% sure on it is OP wants, though my assumption is that the texture wraps seamlessly if made 3D.